# ServiceAuthorizationManager not called

Tags: c#, wcf, soa

I have a very simple ServiceAuthorizationManager (perhaps the simplest) and have followed various tutorials on the web but for some reason none of my breakpoints are hit and this leads to me thinking that its not being called.

- Created a WCF Service Application named it WcfTest
- Kept the default classes Service1.svc, IService.cs but changed method to return a string
- Added a new class that inherits from ServiceAuthorizationManager
- Overridden the method CheckAccessCore()
- Adjusted web.config so that it uses this manager class
- Run the WCF Service Application
- Assembly is called WcfTest
- All classes live in root of the project no folders or anything

Invoke the method and at this point I am expecting my ServiceAuthorizationManager to be called or am I wrong here? I thought the whole purpose of it was to hit the custom ServiceAuthorizationManager on every request received?

Thanks in advance, Onam.

Any more info required let me know, will be watching this like a hawk as I am very confused when this should apparently be very simple.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/getIt",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetIt();
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetIt()
    {
        return "boo!";
    }
}

public class MyServiceMan : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        try
        {
            //Some stuff here breakpoint set on above line not hit
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfTest.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
                  contract="WcfTest.IService1"
                  binding="webHttpBinding">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WcfTest.MyServiceMan,WcfTest" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing endpoint behavior?

```
behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpEndpointBehavior"

<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttpEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by setting breakpoint in my `CustomAuthorizationManager CheckAccessCore` method and start debugging my WCF project in Visual Studio. Then I run from my desktop WCF Client App and execute some method and it's done.